# Pip installation on virtual environment throwing error on versions of dependency package

Tags: python, pip

We are trying to install **OpenStack Services**. We have created the virtual environment and installed Pip as well. Pip version is 8.1.1. Now when we try to install keystone we getting the error with dependency package as below:

```
/tmp/openstack-venv-builder/venvs/horizon/bin/pip install --timeout 120 --find-links /var/www/repo/os-releases/liberty --no-index --log /var/log/repo/repo_venv_builder.log keystone
Ignoring indexes: http://pypi.python.org/simple
Collecting keystone
Collecting oslo.i18n<1.6.0,>=1.5.0 (from keystone)

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement oslo.i18n<1.6.0,>=1.5.0 (from keystone) (from versions: 3.1.0)
No matching distribution found for oslo.i18n<1.6.0,>=1.5.0 (from keystone)
```

Installation on **oslo.i18n** looks fine.

```
/tmp/openstack-venv-builder/venvs/horizon/bin/pip install --timeout 120 --find-links /var/www/repo/os-releases/liberty --no-index --log /var/log/repo/repo_venv_builder.log oslo.i18n
Ignoring indexes: http://pypi.python.org/simple
Collecting oslo.i18n
Collecting pbr>=1.6 (from oslo.i18n)
Collecting Babel>=1.3 (from oslo.i18n)
Collecting six>=1.9.0 (from oslo.i18n)
Collecting pytz>=0a (from Babel>=1.3->oslo.i18n)
Installing collected packages: pbr, pytz, Babel, six, oslo.i18n
Successfully installed Babel-2.1.1 oslo.i18n-3.1.0 pbr-1.8.1 pytz-2015.7 six-1.10.0


Even then we are getting error while installing keystone. Please help.
```

Comment: It's not clear from this that you've activated the virtual environment. Do <envname>/bin/activate. When your shell prompt changes to reflect the name of the environment, first try upgrading pip before continuing: pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: Also, you should post the actual error

Comment: i have pasted the error in first code block .  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement oslo.i18n<1.6.0,>=1.5.0 (from keystone) (from versions: 3.1.0)
No matching distribution found for oslo.i18n<1.6.0,>=1.5.0 (from keystone)